# Pandas dataframe difference in same column by date

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

I want to minus the data from 5 days ago.

For example:
Id:1, Date: 6/10/2023, Data: 22.
Id:1, Date: 6/5/2023, Data: 15

Result:
Id:1, Date: 6/10/2023, Data: 22, Diff: 7

Please see the image.

[image: Data Set]

Comment: please do not use images of data/code, replace it with a reproducible example **as text**

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a sample excel file:

[image]

With the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df=pd.read_csv('a.csv')
diff=[]
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
for i in range(0,len(df['date'])):

    localdf=df.loc[(df['date']==df['date'][i] -datetime.timedelta(days=5))&(df['id'] == df['id'][i])]
    if localdf.empty:
        diff.append(0)
    else:
        localdf=localdf.reset_index()
        diff.append(df['value'][i]-localdf['value'][0])



df['diff']=diff
```

gives:

[image]